# Recover the axis and angle of rotation between $2$ line segments in $3$D

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given two directed line-segments in $3$D space, where it is known one segment is a rotation of the other about some axis, through some point, by some angle, how might you recover the axis and angle from the end-points of the segments?

Comment: Hint: If the first line segment is $AB$ and the second is $CD$, assume that $A$ rotates into $C$ and $B$ into $D$.  The axis of rotation is along the line of intersection of two planes:  The first plane has $AC$ as its normal vector and passes through the midpoint of $AC$, while the second plane has $BD$ as its normal vector and passes through the midpoint of $BD$.  Create the rotation matrix using Rodrigues' Rotation Matrix Formula, then find the angle of rotation by using the pair $A,C$ or the pair $B, D$.

Comment: Special Cases:  If the two planes described above do not intersect (parallel) then no rotation is possible that will bring $AB$ to $CD$.  If the two planes are identical, then the axis of rotation can be chosen to be along any direction in this plane, but passing through the intersection point of $AB$ and $CD$.